# How a typical cluster of five servers can tolerate the failure of any two servers?

Tags: distributed-system, fault-tolerance, raft

I am reading Raft-extended paper and above statement was there. Also I found a statement in the web saying failures of `f` servers can be tolerated if there were `2*f+1` servers. It's obvious to have another two servers where `f=1`. Is there an inductive way to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is intuitive once you realize that for any operation to be successful, it must complete successfully on a majority of the servers. i.e. in case of a discrepancy, at least quorum number of servers must agree on the same value.

For 2 servers, both servers must be in agreement for a majority.

For 3 servers, at least 2 must be in agreement for a majority.

For 4 servers, at least 3 must be in agreement for a majority.

For 5 servers, at least 3 must be in agreement for a majority.

i.e. for `n` servers, `n/2 +1` servers must be in agreement.

So for `n` servers, the number of servers that can afford to **fail** is `n - (n/2+1)`.

Which mean for `2n` servers, it is `2n - (2n/2 + 1)`.

Therefore for `2n +1` servers, it is `2n - (2n/2 + 1) + 1`, which simplifies to `n` servers.

Comment: Thanks @itisravi, It makes sense to me. There should to at least (half +1) servers up and running for failed servers to agree on the replicated values are correct.